# Failed to store an array within array nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am working on a chat application. I have chat history in chats table. Now I want to see the latest message of each chat by using the sender email. So, I am getting the chat id by using distinct query as shown below

```
var userChat = [];
```

```
Chat.distinct("chatId", {"senderEmail" : req.params.Email}, function(err, result){
  if( result){
    console.log(result);

    for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++){
      Chat.find({ chatId: result[i] }).sort('-_id').limit(1).exec(function(error, result) 
        {
        if(result){
          console.log(" IN FOR LOOP ");
          userChat.push(result);
        }
      });
    }  

    console.log("USER CHAT ARRAY :  ", userChat);

  }

});
```

After running the distinct query I got 4 chat ids [ '114143', '130997', '457884', '479310' ]

Now the problem is that whenever I call push then it is not pushing result array from find query into the userChat array. Also I have noticed that the console of USER CHAT ARRAY is called BEFORE for loop console. 
Following is the screenshot of the console

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each `Chat.find()` operation is asynchronous, so your for loop creates and finished the iteration. By the time you hit `console.log("USER CHAT ARRAY :  ", userChat);` none of this operations has finished yet.

Thats by you see `USER CHAT ARRAY: []` and then `IN FOR LOOP` on the console.

You need to `await` each of this `Chat.find()` operations like so:

```js
Chat.distinct("chatId", {"senderEmail" : req.params.Email}, async function(err, result){
  if( result){
    console.log(result);

    for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++){
      try {
        var chat = await Chat.find({ chatId: result[i] }).sort('-_id').limit(1).exec();
        if(chat){
          console.log(" IN FOR LOOP ");
          userChat.push(chat);
        }
      } catch (e) {
        //Handle errors here
      }
    }  
    console.log("USER CHAT ARRAY :  ", userChat);
  }
});
```

The changes:

1. Mark Chat.distinct callback function with `async`
2. In for loop, `await` each Chat.find() query
3. Use try/catch to handle errors

Comment: Thank you for explaining. I tried it and I got a result in USER CHAT ARRAY but for chat id which is on index 0. It did not return the find result for chat ids that are on index 1 to 3.

Comment: sorry I made a mistake, I use the result variable inside the for loop and has the same name as the variable from outside. I will change it to `chat`